# PHPUnit autoload, class not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, autoload

I am trying to run unit test in `crm Zurmo`. Following command entered in console produces errors:

```
phpunit EmailTemplateTest.php

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ZurmoBaseTest' not found in /zurmo/app/protected/modules/emailTemplates/tests/unit/EmailTemplateTest.php on line 38

Fatal error: Class 'ZurmoBaseTest' not found in /zurmo/app/protected/modules/emailTemplates/tests/unit/EmailTemplateTest.php on line 38
```

I realize that it's problem with `autoload`, but don't know how resolve this.

Comment: Are you using a bootstrap file with an autoloader to load other classes?